# How to display rotated columns names in dataset?

Tags: dataset

Consider the following minimalist `Dataset`:

```
Query[All,All]@<|
    1-><|1->"data11",2->"data12"|>,
    2-><|1->"data21",2->"data22"|>
|>//Dataset
```

Its columns names `1` and `2` are not strings so the `Dataset` doesn't display them as columns but rather as nested rows. If i turn them into strings they display properly.

```
Query[All,KeyMap[ToString]]@<|
    1-><|1->"data11",2->"data12"|>,
    2-><|1->"data21",2->"data22"|>
|>//Dataset
```

But the problem I am facing is that my dataset has a lot of columns with large string names. So I want to rotate their names so they display within my screen.

```
Query[All,KeyMap[Rotate["very large named column "<>ToString@#,90\[Degree]]&]]@<|
    1-><|1->"data11",2->"data12"|>,
    2-><|1->"data21",2->"data22"|>
|>//Dataset
```

Is there a way to get it to display as a column rather than nested rows?

After rotating or restyling the string to reduce its font size changes its type so the `StringQ` returns `False`.

Are there native string operations available in Wolfram language which after transformation returns a `String` rather than some other expression.

Comment: `Query[All,KeyMap[ToString[Rotate["very large named column "<>ToString@#,90\[Degree]], StandardForm]&]]` ? (Need to figure out how to display the whole label.)

Comment: Is this the way we'd rotate the column names (and not a query)?  I ask because I tried various forms of Rotate with HeaderDisplayFunction and nothing is working.  This might be a different question.